# Recognize file types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-type

Is there out there a powershell script that does what http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html does?

Namely: giving a list of probabilities that a certain file is a certain file? (based on clues like extension, magic bytes, contents, other files in the same folder, installed apps, etc... etc...)

Comment: I'm not aware of such a script. It would need to retain a database to compare this information. Why reinvent the wheel? Why not just call the utility from PowerShell? Otherwise this would be a huge endevour.

Comment: well its not for work dev its for a home dev, so i have the time

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snip I wrote you to identify .AVI files from powershell.  It's well known that all AVI files begin with the `RIFF` header which you can see with any hex editor. This script grabs the first four bytes and converts them from binary to hex before comparing them against the expected result of `52 49 46 46` aka `RIFF`

http://file-extension.net/seeker/file_extension_avi

```
$a = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Some.avi");

$header += "{0:X2}" -f $a[0]
$header += "{0:X2}" -f $a[1]
$header += "{0:X2}" -f $a[2]
$header += "{0:X2}" -f $a[3]

$header

If ($header -eq "52494646") {Write-Host "File contains an AVI header."} Else {Write-Host "File does not contain an AVI header."}
```

If you have time, it can be done.   Maybe take a look here.

http://www.filesignatures.net/